# Is there a command line option to pipe GCC result to console? Or bash?

Tags: bash, gcc, command-line, pipe

Title about says it: I'm wondering if there is a `gcc` option or a bash option to output the result into the console, rather than a file?

I'm not very savvy with bash scripting, where I suspect there must be an answer... I have searched the GCC manual and wasn't able to find anything definitive.

**Examples**

`~$ clang ~/program_name.c -S -emit-llvm -o -`  will output the intermediate representation to the console.

**The best I have come up with is:**

`~$ gcc -Wall program_name.c -o program_name.o && nano program_name.o` It works, but an actual print would be nice.

---

It would be nice if *most* `gcc` compiles could be printed to the console... from `gcc -Wall program_name.c` to `gcc -fdump-tree-ssa program_name.c`.

Comment: What do you mean by "an actual print would be nice"? Do you just want to `cat program_name.o`?

Comment: I mean the result will be output to the console, as in the `clang` example.

Comment: This cannot be done. `GCC` requires the ability to seek in its output file and you cannot seek on a pipe. Why would you ever want to do this anyway?

Comment: @DarkFalcon Thanks for the information; if a file is necessary for `gcc` to do its work then there is surely a way to immediately pipe the output file into the console. I will adjust the question...

Comment: Yes: `cat`, as drewmm mentioned. I am still not understanding why you would ever want to dump a binary object file to your console though.

Comment: Yes, cat seems to be an improved version of my current method... @DarkFalcon Yes, printing binary object files is not the  most effective use of one's console, but it expedites the examining of intermediate representations nicely :) I asked about all `gcc` compiles because I was curious if there was a `gcc` option that could be passed as with `clang`, as my question illustrated. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work on Linux:

```
g++ -Wall program_name.c -o /dev/fd/1
```